# Regular expression in Java with spaces

Tags: java, regex

Please help make regular expression that converts following string:

```
A [B C] "D E F"
```

into 3 strings

1. `A`
2. `B C`
3. `D E F`

where A, B, C, D, E, F are a set of alphanumeric characters and may or may not include special characters such as +:/._- etc.

I tried something like: `[[a-zA-Z0-9/: +]+]\s"[a-zA-Z0-9._/?&=-]+"\s[a-zA-Z0-9-]+`.

But this returns single recognized pattern when I use Java's Pattern and Matcher classes. I want to get 3 distinct groups.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please do your own homework

Comment: I tried something like: [[a-zA-Z0-9/: +]+\]\s"[a-zA-Z0-9._/?&=-]+"\s[a-zA-Z0-9-]+. But this returns single recognized pattern when I use Java's Pattern and Matcher classes. I want to get 3 distinct groups.

Comment: What is an 'unrecognized pattern'?

Comment: Are the brackets nested ? Could there be escaped quotes ? Something like `A [B [C D]] "E\" F"` ? If so what is the expected output ? You most likely will need to write your own parser if this is the case ...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your attempt correctly the answer could be pretty simple:

```
String test = "A [B C] \"D E F\"";
//                            | any number of characters (group 1) followed by...
//                            |   | one whitespace, followed by
//                            |   |  | left square bracket, f.b...
//                            |   |  |  | any number of characters (group 2), f.b...
//                            |   |  |  |  | right square bracket, f.b...
//                            |   |  |  |  |   | one whitespace, f.b...
//                            |   |  |  |  |   |  | one double quote, f.b...
//                            |   |  |  |  |   |  | | any number of characters (group 3) f.b...
//                            |   |  |  |  |   |  | |    | one double quote
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)\\s\\[(.+)\\]\\s\"(.+?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

**Output**

```
A
B C
D E F
```

**Note**

Replace the dot characters with classes or other generalizations if you want more specific ranges of characters to be matched to your groups 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I was not using group operators ( & ). Thanks again.